# in function return prime numbers = TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()` when trying to run the following code. Can somebody help me locate the problem?

```py
def prime_numbers(nb):
    if nb < 0:
        return None
    if nb == 0:
        return []
    primes = [2, 3]
    n = primes[-1] + 2
    while len(primes) < nb:
        for p in primes:
            if n % p == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(n)
        n += 2
    return primes


print(prime_numbers(10))
print(prime_numbers(0))
```

Comment: I ran the code you posted and I don't get any error message.

Comment: There are no strings anywhere in this code. Are you perhaps getting your numbers from `input()` in your "real" code?

Comment: The code you have posted works well. Perhaps the error comes from another part of your main code.. Check it!

Comment: Thank you all. I'll check it.